# How can we increment or decrement date in java (JUST DATE)

Tags: java

I want to display complete date in mySQL format but don't want to see the Time along with it.

Wanted to increment or decrement the date to perform actions

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class )
.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) 
.toLocalDate()
.toString()
```

## Details

For a column of type akin to the SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`, retrieve as a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = myResultSet.getObject( … , Instant.class ) ;
```

An `Instant` is always in UTC. Adjust into the time zone by which you want to perceive the date according to the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region. For any given moment, the date varies around the world by zone. It might be “tomorrow” in `Asia/Kolkata` India while still “yesterday” in `America/Montreal` Canada.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only, as that is what you want to focus on.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

Use the various plus/minus methods to add or subtract days, weeks, months, years, or a combination of those (`Period`).

```
LocalDate dayAfter = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
```

Or…

```
Period p = Period.parse( "P3M7D" ) ;
LocalDate later = ld.plus( p ) ;
```

For a database type akin to SQL-standard `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`, retrieve as a `LocalDateTime`. Skip the part above with time zone. Go directly to extracting the `LocalDate`. Proceed with your addition/subtraction.

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class )
.toLocalDate()
.plusDays( 1 ) 
.toString()
```

To generate a String representing the date value in standard ISO 8601 format, call `LocalDate::toString()`. For other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.